# How can I create an array of classes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have created two classes, StepsCell and WeightCell

```
import UIKit

class StepsCell {
    let name = "Steps"
    let count = 2000
}


import UIKit

class WeightCell {

    let name = "Weight"
    let kiloWeight = 90
}
```

In my VC I attempt to create an array, cellArray, to hold the objects.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController {

    var stepsCell = StepsCell()
    var weightCell = WeightCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var cellArray = [stepsCell, weightCell]
        println(StepsCell().name)
        println(stepsCell.name)
        println(cellArray[0].name)
}
```

but when I index into the array :

```
println(cellArray[0].name)
```

I get nil.. Why?  How can I create an array that "holds" these classes and that I can index into to get the various variables (and functions to be added later).  I thought this would be a super simple thing but I can't find any answers for this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your array is not holding 'classes' it is holding 'instances of classes'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you create an array with mixed types. Because of this, the compiler doesn't know the type of the object returned by `cellArray[0]`. It infers that this object must be of type `AnyObject`. Apparently this has a property named `name`, which returns nil.

The solution is to either cast it `println((cellArray[0] as StepsCell).name)`, or use a common protocol or superclass:

```
protocol Nameable {
    var name: String { get }
}

class StepsCell: Nameable {
    let name = "Steps"
    let count = 2000
}

class WeightCell: Nameable {
    let name = "Weight"
    let kiloWeight = 90
}

var stepsCell = StepsCell()
var weightCell = WeightCell()

var cellArray: [Nameable] = [stepsCell, weightCell]
println(StepsCell().name)
println(stepsCell.name)
println(cellArray[0].name)
```

Comment: ok, I get it.  cellArray[0] as StepsCell).name) would not work for me, because  cellArray[0] might just as well be WeightCell.  I know what a protocol is, but have no idea what a superclass is.

Comment: Then I suggest you start learning OOP first: http://www.raywenderlich.com/81952/intro-object-oriented-design-swift-part-1

Comment: Thanks - I went through the tutorial that you recommended.  Thank you also for explaining the the logic of the compiler in such an intuitive manner.

Answer (score 2):

As @Rengers said in his answer you may use the approach,
To drill down to your code you can solve it like this,

```
class StepsCell {
let name = "Steps"
let cellCount = 2000
}

class WeightCell {
let name = "Weight"
let weightCount = 90
}


var stepcell = StepsCell() // creating the object
var weightcell = WeightCell()


// Your array where you store both the object
var myArray = [stepcell,weightcell];

// creating a temp object for StepsCell
let tempStepCell = myArray[0] as StepsCell

println(tempStepCell.name)
```

Your array is holding the instance of the classes which you created so you may use a temp variable to extract those values OR to make it more simpler you may also do something like this

```
((myArray[0]) as StepsCell ).name
```

Since you have two classes and at run time we just love to keep things dynamic you can add a conditional operator which would identify the type of object you want to work with

```
if let objectIdentification = myArray[0] as? StepsCell {
println("Do operations with steps cell object here")
}else{
println("Do operation with weight cell object here")

}
```

Comment: ok, I like your train of thought, but I actually have 18 of these classes, so maybe a protocol is better?

Comment: @karlml that hurts really bad, I think better would be to create a base class for all those 18 classes and then add them in the array that would simplify things a lot and then you can do the identification of objects on runtime.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting.  Presuming hurts means, hurts performance?, is it better to have one baseclass with lots of subclasses than lots of separate classes?

Comment: @karlml If you have one base class with tons of subclasses then its pretty much ok, performance depends upon how we code and iterate things anyways you can use the instruments if you are that much concerned about the memory related issues.