# Swift - create an array of classes

Tags: swift

I [saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145564/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-classes-in-swift), but what I want is to create an array of the actual classes so that I can call a class function on each of them.

Example:

```
let syncClasses:[Any] = [Battery, Tank, Gas]
for object in syncClasses {
  object.someClassMethod()
}
```

I tried using `[Any]` as a type for the array but that threw:

```
Expected member name or constructor call after type name
```

All of the classes inherit from the same `Object` class so I can hack it by doing:

```
let syncClasses:[Object] = [Battery(), Tank()]
```

but then I have to make the function I want to call a method instead of a class function and that's not as clean as I would like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *swifty* way is to use a protocol:

```
protocol Drainable {
  static func drain()
}

class Battery : Drainable {
  static func drain() { print("battery drained") }
}

class Tank  : Drainable {
  static func drain() { print("tank drained") }
}

class Gas  : Drainable {
  static func drain() { print("gas drained") }
}

let syncClasses : [Drainable.Type] = [Battery.self, Tank.self, Gas.self]

for object in syncClasses {
  object.drain()
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  Is there a standard / rule for when to use protocol to share inheritance vs using a superclass?

Comment: Not really. But don't fight the type system. Many classes in the Apple frameworks which inherit from Objective-C are supposed to be subclassed. It depends on the environment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.self` to get the class type off the class symbol like this:

```
class Battery {
    class func test() {}
}

class Tank {}
class Gas {}

let array: [AnyClass] = [Battery.self, Tank.self, Gas.self]

for thing in array {
    if let battery = thing as? Battery.Type {
        Battery.test()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  That works awesome for creating the array.  But then having to unwrap each class with ```let battery = thing as? Battery.type``` kind of defeats the purpose of saving code as you would have to do that explicitly for each class.

Comment: See Vadian's answer :)